# Como armazenar imagens no MySQL

Tags: php, sql, imagem, criptografia, armazenamento

Fala galera, estou com uma dúvida: cadastrar imagem com criptografia( que fique apenas códigos no DB ) ou cadastrar local da imagem, e salvar a imagem em uma pasta?

OBS: Não sei se cadastrando no BD a criptografia fica mais leve, ou mais pesado, se souberem tbm e puder me informar...

Comment: criptografia ? poderia ser compactação talvez, mas nada tem a ver com armazenar caminho da imagem ou o binário dentro do banco

Comment: ha um tempo atraz um cara aqui do forum falou que dava para converter imagem, video, etc em um 'código' criptografado... ai pensei em cadastrar esse código, ao invez de cadastrar o caminho da imagem e salvar a imagem em uma pasta, pois bastaria puxar o código do DB, e acho que dessa forma ainda nao tem "perigo" de apagar a pasta de imagens e perder tudo